# Delegate methods not being called in swift class

Tags: ios, swift, delegates

I'm integrating an SDK that tracks location points.

The SDK demo app has the SDK framework loaded, and then a UIViewController that extends the SDK delegate.  The SDK calls certain delegate functions as the user moves around - these all work fine in the demo app from the SDK provider.  All the delegate callback functions, like processStart are inside the TripsViewController: UIViewController, TheSDKSwiftDelegate

Example:

```
  import TheSDKSwift
    
        final class TripsViewController: UIViewController, TheSDKSwiftDelegate {
        
    ...
    
        TheSDKSwift.setup(with: configuration, delegate: self, completionHandler: {success, error in
                    if success {
                        successBlock()
                    } else {
                        failureBlock(error)
                    }
                })
    
    ...
    
    // TheSDK Delegate callbacks
        func processStart(ofDrive startInfo: DriveStartInfo) {
            
            self.driveStatusLabel.text = "Driving"
    
            if self.isAccidentEnabled() {
                self.mockAccidentButton.isEnabled = true
            }
    
            let dateString = DateFormatter.shortStyleFormatter.string(from: Date(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval(startInfo.startTimestamp/1000 )))
            NotificationManager.displayNotification(message: "Trip Started: \(dateString)")
        }
        }
```

So during the normal running of the SDK, it then calls back to the processStart method to provide info on what's happening.

Now, in my own app, I can't have these functions/delegates in UIViewController.  I need to have them in a separate Swift file and call the functions from another controller.  When I do that, my SDK initializes, but the delegate methods don't get called by the SDK while it's running, whereas the delegate methods DO get called when everything is in on UIViewController extending the delegate.  Just not when I put it in my own swift file.

Here's a short snippet of what I'm doing:

```
import Foundation
import Capacitor

@objc(TheSDKPlugin)
public class TheSDKPlugin: CAPPlugin {


@objc func SetupSDK(_ call: CAPPluginCall) {
    
    TheSDKPluginWrapper().StartSDK()

}
```

So TheSDKPluginiWrapper().StartSDK() gets called.

```
import Foundation
import TheSDKSwift
import Capacitor

class TheSDKPluginWrapper: NSObject, TheSDKSwiftDelegate {


...
        TheSDKSwift.setup(with: configuration, delegate: self, completionHandler: {success, error in
                    if success {
                        successBlock()
                    } else {
                        failureBlock(error)
                    }
                })
...


// TheSDK Delegate callbacks
        func processStart(ofDrive startInfo: DriveStartInfo) {
            
            self.driveStatusLabel.text = "Driving"
    
            if self.isAccidentEnabled() {
                self.mockAccidentButton.isEnabled = true
            }
    
            let dateString = DateFormatter.shortStyleFormatter.string(from: Date(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval(startInfo.startTimestamp/1000 )))
            NotificationManager.displayNotification(message: "Trip Started: \(dateString)")
        }

}
```

Again, SDK initializes successfully.  But now, SDK never calls the delegate method in TheSDKPluginiWrapper().

How do I retain the delegate throughout, so that SDK delegate methods get called in my swift file, same way it gets called when everything is in UIViewController?

Comment: In `SetupSDK` you are creating an instance of `TheSDKPluginWrapper` as a local, anonymous variable.  This will be discarded as soon as the function exits. You need to save a reference to the instance in a property and also make sure you are holding a reference to the `TheSDKPlugin` object somewhere (Maybe Capacitor does that for you?  I have never used it)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the delegate methods in a separate file, you can just define them as an extension to the class:

```
extension TripsViewController: TheSDKSwiftDelegate {

   // TheSDK Delegate callbacks

   func processStart(ofDrive startInfo: DriveStartInfo) {

   }
   ...
}
```